# Corrective Feedback (Picture as Feedback) in Psychopy

Tags: feedback, psychopy

I am creating an experiment with the PsychoPy Builder.
I have visual and auditory stimuli, the task is to learn associations between them.
When the participant presses the right key, the answer "Correct" appears. However, when the participant presses the wrong key, I would like to not only display "Wrong." But also: "The correct answer is ..." and then show the picture  or the sound of the correct association.

I have created a routine that is called "Feedback". It contains the Code component, the Text component and the Picture component (or the sound component).
In the condition file (.xlsx), the picture (sound) that should be displayed is called "corrective_FB".

In the Code Component in "Begin Experiment", I have

```
  message=''
```

In the Code Component I have written the following code in the "Begin Routine":

```
 if Antwort_manuell.corr:#stored on last run routine
        message="Richtig!"
    else:
        message="Ups, das war falsch. Die richtige Antwort wäre:"
        Form_stimulus2.setImage(corrective_FB)
```

I guess, I am not doing the "display image" command correctly. How is the correct command? And how is it for an auditory stimulus?

When I run the experiment, it seems to work when I press the correct keypress (however, the picture is shown then, too and it should only be the text....), but when I press the wrong key, the experiment stops.

When I force it to end, I get the follwing message:

Running: C:\Dateien\Forschung\Experimente\Legasthenie_Crossmodal\Experiment\Visual_manual\Vis_Man_lastrun.py
Traceback (most recent call last)

**File "C:\Dateien\Forschung\Experimente\Legasthenie_Crossmodal\Experiment\Visual_manual\Vis_Man_lastrun.py", line 406, in** 
Feedbacktext.setText(message)

**File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy-1.82.01-py2.7.egg\psychopy\visual\text.py", line 240, in setText**
setAttribute(self, 'text', text, log)

**File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy-1.82.01-py2.7.egg\psychopy\tools\attributetools.py", line 100, in setAttribute**
setattr(self, attrib, value)  # set attribute, calling attributeSetter if it exists

**File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy-1.82.01-py2.7.egg\psychopy\tools\attributetools.py", line 20, in __set__**
newValue = self.func(obj, value)

**File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy-1.82.01-py2.7.egg\psychopy\visual\text.py", line 231, in text**
self.**dict**['text'] = unicode(text)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 43: ordinal not in range(128)
Exception UnicodeDecodeError:

Comment: What does it show? Does it show the text? Does it play the sound? Also, is the code component above or below the image and sound components in the routine?

Comment: I assume that the text component has text=$message ?

Comment: As I ran it now again, it showed the text and the image, but only when the keypress was correct. If it was wrong, the experiment stops and I have to force it to shut down.
The Code Component is above the image / sound in the routine (on top). Yes, the text component has text=$message.
The feedback worked correctly before I entered the image/ sound.

Comment: Update your question with the error message you get when it crashes. A few usual suspects: are you sure that ``corrective_FB`` is exactly correct, including path and small/big letters? Is your imageStim actually called "Form_stimulus2", also remembering small/capital letters?

Comment: Looks like the issue is with the text rather than the image or sound file names. What happens if you explicitly make it a unicode string, like this: `message=u'Ups, das war falsch. Die richtige Antwort wäre:'`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. I finally got it work. I indeed had to mark the message as a unicode string.
And I had to define more explicitly how the stimulus will be shown for correct and wrong answers. 
I don't know, if I did it the most intelligent way, but it works. I am thankful for suggestions how it can be done more "beautifully", but this is how my code looks like now:

```
    if Antwort_manuell.corr:#stored on last run routine
    message="Richtig!"
    Form_stimulus2.size = 0
else:
    message=u"Ups, das war falsch. Die richtige Antwort wäre:"
    Form_stimulus2.setImage(corrective_FB)
    Form_stimulus2.size = 5
```

And for the sound the code is:

```
    if key_tester.corr:#stored on last run routine
    message="Richtig!"
    sound_1.volume = 0
else:
    message=u"Ups, das war falsch. Die richtige Antwort wäre:"
    sound_1.setSound(corrective_FB)
    sound_1.volume = 1
```